# Why powerdot on Mac (MacTeX 2011) is giving me a shrunk dvi output?

Tags: mactex, dvi, powerdot

I'm trying to use the powerdot class that comes with TeX Live 2011 on Mac OS X Lion (MacTex). I'm using the sample file from docs, powerdot-example.tex. On the command line, I use

> latex powerdot-example.tex
>
> latex powerdot-example.tex

And it gives me a dvi file. However, the contents of this dvi file are much smaller then the paper size, I'm not understading what is the cause of this.

This sample file has a lyx cousin file: powerdot-example.lyx, which I can open in the LyX editor and chose File>Export>DVI from Menu. When I do that, the dvi output is right, and I'm not able to figure out how LyX is doing it right while I'm unable to do the same from the command line.

Also, a detail that is not so important, the sample file tries to use a randomdots slide option which has no effect when opening a pdf file created from the dvi file, while opening the dvi file directly with xdvi shows the random dots background decoration on the given slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out.

I had to **remove the nopsheader class option** from the example source file and also I must use **latex / dvips / ps2pdf** to at last obtain a correct pdf even though the dvi file still wrong.

Using dvipdfm(x) does not produce a correct pdf with powerdot.

Answer (score 1):

`powerdot` works strictly with PostScript specials for `dvips`, so it's very unlikely that it works with `dvipdfm(x)`.

The correct path to get a PDF from a `powerdot` source is

```
latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf
```

which can be shortened with a script present on TeX Live (don't know on MiKTeX)

```
simpdftex latex <filename>
```

The dimensions of the DVI output are mostly irrelevant, as the final PDF will be scaled to fit the screen.