# Wrong paper format with powerdot in TexShop

Tags: paper-size, output, powerdot

I use the powerdot class to create presentations. After the last update of TexLive (I use TexShop on Mac), the paper format (which was landscape by default) has become different (a4 or something alike) and the content of the presentation is shifted so that in the final pdf-File I just see a small part of each slide. For the typesetting I use "TeX and DVI" and unfortunately I couldn't get any solution out of related questions asked on this site. Especially this question [Why powerdot on Mac (MacTeX 2011) is giving me a shrunk dvi output?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55605/why-powerdot-on-mac-mactex-2011-is-giving-me-a-shrunk-dvi-output)
seems to be related but I didn't quite understand the answer. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I use TeXShop 3.87 and I have installed the TexLive-2017 distribution.
A small working example is

```
\documentclass[style=sailor]{powerdot}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{Title}Some content
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Here's a screenshot of the output (it just shows the lower left part of the page):

[image: Screenshot MWE]

The log-file has the following content:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=latex 2017.8.22)  13 SEP 2017 15:54
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mwe.tex
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/powerdot/powerdot.cls
Document Class: powerdot 2015/11/29 v1.5a powerdot presentation class (HA)
\c@note=\count79
\c@slide=\count80
\c@pd@pause=\count81
\c@pd@section=\count82
\c@pd@overlay=\count83
\c@pd@trivlist=\count84
\c@pd@onslidedepth=\count85
\pd@tba=\box26
\pd@tbb=\box27
\pd@body=\toks14
\pd@bmout=\write3
\pd@tocout=\write4
\pd@frsep=\skip41
\pd@colsep=\skip42
\slidewidth=\skip43
\slideheight=\skip44
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count86
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count87
\c@section=\count88
\c@subsection=\count89
\c@subsubsection=\count90
\c@paragraph=\count91
\c@subparagraph=\count92
\c@figure=\count93
\c@table=\count94
\abovecaptionskip=\skip45
\belowcaptionskip=\skip46
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count95
\Gm@cntv=\count96
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count97
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen111
\Hy@linkcounter=\count98
\Hy@pagecounter=\count99

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count100

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `setpagesize' set `false' on input line 4374.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pageanchor' set `false' on input line 4374.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `false' on input line 4374.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4498.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4503.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4513.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4518.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks OFF on input line 4757.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count101

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5104.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen112
\Fld@menulength=\count102
\Field@Width=\dimen113
\Fld@charsize=\dimen114
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6358.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6363.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6366.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6373.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6378.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6383.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6388.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6428.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6432.
\Hy@abspage=\count103
\c@Item=\count104
\c@Hfootnote=\count105
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hdvips.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
File: hdvips.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for dvips

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
File: pdfmark.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
\pdf@docset=\toks18
\pdf@box=\box28
\pdf@toks=\toks19
\pdf@defaulttoks=\toks20
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count106
\Fld@listcount=\count107
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count108

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip47
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/04/14 v1.1b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 99.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2016/07/10 v3.1a Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen115
\Gin@req@width=\dimen116
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
Package: pstricks 2017/03/17 v0.63 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count109
\pstFP@xia=\count110
\pstFP@xib=\count111
\pstFP@xfa=\count112
\pstFP@xfb=\count113
\pstFP@rega=\count114
\pstFP@regb=\count115
\pstFP@regs=\count116
\pstFP@times=\count117
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks21
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen117
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen118

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks22
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks23

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks24
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen119
\pgf@xa=\dimen120
\pgf@xb=\dimen121
\pgf@xc=\dimen122
\pgf@y=\dimen123
\pgf@ya=\dimen124
\pgf@yb=\dimen125
\pgf@yc=\dimen126
\c@pgf@counta=\count118
\c@pgf@countb=\count119
\c@pgf@countc=\count120
\c@pgf@countd=\count121
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count122
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count123
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen127
\pgfmath@count=\count124
\pgfmath@box=\box29
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count125
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen128
\pgffor@skip=\dimen129
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
)
\psLoopIndex=\count126

`PSTricks' v2.73  <2017/05/18> (tvz)
\pst@dima=\dimen130
\pst@dimb=\dimen131
\pst@dimc=\dimen132
\pst@dimd=\dimen133
\pst@dimg=\dimen134
\pst@dimh=\dimen135
\pst@dimm=\dimen136
\pst@dimn=\dimen137
\pst@dimo=\dimen138
\pst@dimp=\dimen139
\pst@hbox=\box30
\pst@ibox=\box31
\pst@boxg=\box32
\pst@cnta=\count127
\pst@cntb=\count128
\pst@cntc=\count129
\pst@cntd=\count130
\pst@cntg=\count131
\pst@cnth=\count132
\pst@cntm=\count133
\pst@cntn=\count134
\pst@cnto=\count135
\pst@cntp=\count136
\@zero=\count137
\pst@toks=\toks30
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con)
\psunit=\dimen140
\psxunit=\dimen141
\psyunit=\dimen142
\pst@C@@rType=\count138
\pslinewidth=\dimen143
\psk@startLW=\dimen144
\psk@endLW=\dimen145
\pst@customdefs=\toks31
\pslinearc=\dimen146
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen147
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen148
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen149
\everypsbox=\toks32
\psframesep=\dimen150
\pslabelsep=\dimen151
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen152
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen153
\pst@shift=\dimen154
)
File: pstricks.tex 2017/05/18 v2.73 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
File: pst-fp.tex 2017/05/18 v2.73 `PST-fp' (hv)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-ovl/pst-ovl.sty
Package: pst-ovl 2014/01/02 v0.01 LaTeX wrapper for `pst-ovl' (HV)
File: pst-ovl.tex 2014/05/12 v0.06 overlay macros `pst-ovl' (HV)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-ovl/pst-ovl.tex
`pst-ovl' v0.07, 2016/05/03 (tvz,hv)
\thepsoverlaybox=\box33
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
\enitkv@toks@=\toks33
\labelindent=\skip48
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen155
\enit@toks=\toks34
\enit@inbox=\box34
\enitdp@description=\count139
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks35
\verbatim@line=\toks36
\verbatim@in@stream=\read1
)
\pd@logobox=\box35

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/powerdot/powerdot-sailor.sty
Package: powerdot-sailor 2005/12/10 v1.3 sailor style (MH,HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count140
\calc@Bcount=\count141
\calc@Adimen=\dimen156
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen157
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count142
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks37
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-grad/pst-grad.sty
Package: pst-grad 2004/07/15 package wrapper for pst-grad.tex (hv)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-grad/pst-grad.tex
`pst-grad' v1.06, 2006/11/27 (tvz,dg,hv))
File: pst-grad.tex 2006/11/27 1.06 `pst-grad' (tvz)
)))
No file mwe.aux.
\openout1 = `mwe.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+phv on input line 2.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd
File: ot1phv.fd 2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.30756pt on input line 2.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: dvips
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: landscape 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(0.0pt, 794.96999pt, 0.0pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(298.11374pt, 298.11375pt, 0.0pt)
* \paperwidth=1589.9353pt
* \paperheight=1192.44385pt
* \textwidth=794.96999pt
* \textheight=298.11375pt
* \oddsidemargin=-72.26999pt
* \evensidemargin=-72.26999pt
* \topmargin=188.84375pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=36.13718pt
* \voffset=25.13718pt
* \mag=2000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box36
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 2.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count143
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 2.


Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

\openout3 = `mwe.bm'.

\openout4 = `mwe.toc'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.24008pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.24008pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 4.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 4.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.80005pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.80005pt on input line 4.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `lastslide' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 5.
[1

]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 5.
 (./mwe.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 5.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 5.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13325 strings out of 492996
 226319 string characters out of 6132730
 320064 words of memory out of 5000000
 16728 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 11178 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,5n,70p,472b,330s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on mwe.dvi (1 page, 6016 bytes).
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please give us a little more information: what kind of update did you do, was it a complete version upgrade (e.g. from TeX Live 2016 to TeX Live 2017) or did you just update the installed packages (which ones specifically?). Also welcome would be a short [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), a log file of the LaTeX run and a picture or PDF of the compiled output.

Comment: I edited my question to add the missing information.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381413/output-difference-between-mactex-2015-and-2017-with-powerdot-class

Comment: Thank you: How can I make this option dvips -L0 work with TeXShop?

Comment: @frog Better update your tex distribution, see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382854/36296

Comment: I have the latest version now and I updated everything with the "TeX Live Utility" but it still doesn't work. Do I have to modify something within the preferences? Or can I just update powerdot separately?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Apparently, my TexDistribution does not have the most recent powerdot file. How might I change this manually?

Comment: I have version 1.5c, updated with TeX Live Utility; the revision number of the package is 45165.